# jQuery - problem with buttons in content loaded from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Im using the buttons from jQuery UI like this:

```
("button").button();
```

Simple..

But when i use the  tag in a file loaded by ajax, the button script is not applied the button.

Ex: file.php:

```
<button>Testbutton</button>
```

When the this file is loaded on a page with ("button").button(); like this:

```
$("#updateDiv").load(file.php);
```

.. the button is not applied the jQuery UI script.

I've taken a look at the jQuery "live"-function, but it doesnt seem to work for me :(

Comment: Is this your actual code? What your question shows will throw errors.

Comment: Are you sure when the file is loaded then the code `("button").button();` is coming and it is under <script>

Comment: No, this is nok the actual code, just examples. I'm using buttons on the page which works fine, but the problem occurs only when buttons are loaded through ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.live()` doesn't work because it only handles UI events (`click`, `dblclick`, `mousedown`, etc.). You need to supply a callback to `.load()`:

```
$("#updateDiv").load('file.php', function (){
    $(this).find('button').button();
});
```

Comment: Hi again. I have an additional question. Instead of "$(this).find('button').button();" is it possible to load a js file with the different jQuery statements?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to init your button in the callback function:

```
$("#updateDiv").load('file.php', function() { $('button').button(); });
```

Optionally you can use ajaxSuccess:

```
$('#updateDiv').ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $('button', this).button();
});
```

This will init all your buttons inside your div every time a load is successfuly called on your div. See http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the .button function in the callback of the AJAX request so that it is run on the new content placed in the DOM.

```
$("#updateDiv").load('file.php', function() {  
    $("button").button();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the called Ajax page has to have the JQuery UI CSS file imported